# php artisan migration adding foreign key

Tags: php, laravel

No puedo crear la migracion en laravel 5.8, me muestra el siguien error

Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'articles' already exists (SQL: create table `articles` (`id` bigint unsigned not null auto_increment primary key, `author_id` int unsigned not null, `title` varchar(191) not null, `created_at` timestamp null, `updated_at` timestamp null) default character set utf8mb4 collate 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci')

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateCommentsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('comments', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('article_id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('author_id');
            $table->text('body');
            $table->timestamps();

            //FK
            $table->foreign('article_id')
            ->references('id')->on('articles')
            ->onDelete('cascade');

            $table->foreign('author_id')
            ->references('id')->on('people')
            ->onDelete('cascade');

            $table->index('user_id');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropForeign('article_id');
        Schemma::dropForeign('author_id');
        Schema::dropIndex('dropIndex');
        Schemma::dropPrimary('comments');
    }
}
```

Comment: segun error es que ya tienes creada esa tabla, ve a tu base de datos, borrala y vuelve a ejecutar php artisan migrate

Comment: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint (SQL: alter table `articles` add constraint `articles_author_id_foreign` foreign key (`author_id`) references `people` (`id`)) me sigue mostrando este error

Comment: Como te indican la segun el error ya existe una tabla o vesta con ese nombre. Puedes eliminar dicha tabla o tambien ejecutar `php artisan migrate:fresh` para que elimine todas las tablas antes de ejecutar las migraciones nuevamente

Comment: no puedo anadir la llave foranea

Comment: El error que acabas de añadir es diferente, es posible que estes tratando de añadir la clave foranea antes de crear la tabla padre de la que depende, si es un proyecto nuevo, lo mas facil es editar los nombres de los archivos de migracion para que se ejecuten en el orden necesario.

Comment: intenta utilizar esta estructura para tu llave foranea `$table->bigInteger('category_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
            $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories');` solo sustituye lo que esta en parentesis por lo que necesites

Comment: continua el error

Comment: gracias tengo que corregir el orden de las migraciones saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Al no ejecutar la migración en una transacción, al falla en mitad del proceso se quedan algunas creadas pero no registradas en la tabla `migrations`, por eso aunque hagas un rollback no te las eliminara.

La solución es fácil, pon una transacción.